# how to reuse a first template inside a second div

Tags: vue.js

Here I have written two steps one is "step===1" and other one is "step===2". So here i wants to reuse step1 template to step2. That means we have step one template and at step1 we click on next button so at next step i want to show the same template like reusing..

```
<div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <h4>Address</h4>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="address">

    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="city">

    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="state">

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

 </div>
<div v-if="step === 2">
    reuse step===1 template here
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            address: null,
            city: null,
            state: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably separate the form for each step into its own component. So for instance:

**AddressForm.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="localValue.address" />

    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="localValue.city" />

    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="localValue.state" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: Object,
  },
  computed: {
    localValue: {
      get() { return this.value; },
      set(value) { this.$emit("input", value); },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And then just reuse this component for each step:

```
<div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <h4>Address</h4>
    
    <AddressForm v-model="step1address />

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

 </div>
<div v-if="step === 2">
    <h1>Step Two</h1>
    <h4>Address 2</h4>

    <AddressForm v-model="step2address />

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Here's a running sample of the above:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-antonelli-2n4vb

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what i am searching for but it is not working at my side so will you please provide me as working demo. This will help me a lot please.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a link to a running sample of my suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      stepTotal: 2,
      step: 1,
      
      address: null,
      city: null,
      state: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="index of stepTotal">
    <div v-if="step === index" :key="index">
        <h1>Step {{index}}</h1>
        <h4>Address</h4>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="address">

        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="city">

        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="state">

        <br>
        <button v-if="index != 1" @click.prevent="prev()">Prev</button>
        <button v-if="index != stepTotal" @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
     </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for  providing me the answer . but I am trying to achieve without for loop